# datagridview index change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, indexing

How to change the current row of a datagridview in c# by clicking on a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 Yuriy

Also if you wish to move the selection arrow and your row isn't visible then:

```
grid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = grid.Rows[2].Index;
DataGgridridView1.Refresh()
grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows[2].Cells(1) // need to ensure that this is an existing, visible cell

grid.Rows[2].Selected = True
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean changing the selected row index, this should work:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grid.ClearSelection();
    // Select the third row.
    grid.Rows[2].Selected = true;
}
```

If you'd like to swap rows (e.g., interchange data in 1st and 3rd rows), here's an option:

```
int currentRowIndex = 0;
int newRowIndex = 2;

var currentRow = grid.Rows[currentRowIndex];
var rowToReplace = grid.Rows[newRowIndex];

grid.Rows.Remove(currentRow);
grid.Rows.Remove(rowToReplace);
grid.Rows.Insert(currentRowIndex, rowToReplace);
grid.Rows.Insert(newRowIndex, currentRow);
```

Comment: I wana change the current row. For example the current row position is 5 I want to change it to 8.

Comment: @user1235144: What do you mean? You mean moving the row with its data to a different position or just changing the selection?

Comment: Just changing the small black arrow to another record.

Comment: @user1235144: I added a snippet for swapping rows to my answer. Please see if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my Question. I have button with it's name NEXT. And I have a grid view. I want the snippet to go to the next record when the user clicks NEXT. I want to move across the records. –